# Passive Voice and Word Choice Misuse

Tags: word-choice, passive-voice

I checked the sentences below for grammar issues at the Grammarly application. I got three notifications (two-word choice and passive voice misuse). I'm using the free version of the application and I didn't figure out the problem. Can you help me, please?

*Two instructional videos about financial issues were selected from a public TV channel archive. The first one included on-screen texts located at the bottom of and the other one included on-screen texts located at the right part of the screen.*

Comment: “the bottom of” is VERY far away from “the screen” you’d be better off putting it in in the first reference and then either drop it in the second part or just leave our in for both.   I don’t see anything wrong with the rest of it.

Comment: Given that you've stated that the texts were "on-screen", there's no need to then specify "of the screen"

Comment: Based on your comments, I revised the second sentence as "_The first one included on-screen texts located at the bottom and the other one included texts located at the right part of the screen_"

Comment: A comma after _bottom_ would make it even clearer. BTW, there is no passive misuse here. In fact, I would mistrust any software that claimed there were such a thing. -1 for Grammarly.

Comment: @HamzaPolat If you want to get Grammarly to quiet down, restate the first sentence in the active voice (because stylistically, the passive voice is disfavored except when the subject is being concealed), drop "located" (because "at" implies location), and change "the other *one*" to "the other" (because there only is one other, making the word itself unnecessary).

Comment: Since we can't differentiate between the two selected videos, its strange to call one *the first one*. We wouldn't be able to tell which is the first one. I'd replace *the first one* with *one of which* or something similar.

Comment: @remarkl Yep, if you want to make your English rubbish to validate Grammarly, try that. But that isn't what you should do, though! Just uninstall Grammarly!

Comment: @Araucaria - I agree.  I ran out of characters before I could add that I was not endorsing the changes, just identifying the errors according to Grammarly.

Comment: @remarkl Sorry, I have to give Grammarly a hefty boot in the behind whenever I walk past it ;-)